# K8S baremetal nginx-ingress-controller

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, bare-metal-server

> OS: RHEL7 | k8s version: 1.12/13 | kubespray | baremetal

I have a standard kubespray bare metal cluster deployed and I am trying to understand what is the simplest recommended way to deploy nginx-ingress-controller that will allow me to deploy simple services. There is no load balancer provided. I want my MASTER public IP as the endpoint for my services.

[image: look-up]

Github k8s ingress-nginx [suggests](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/master/docs/deploy/index.md#bare-metal) NodePort service as a "mandatory" step, which seems not to be enough to make it works along with kubespray's *ingress_controller*.

I was able to make it working forcing LoadBalancer service type and setting externalIP value as a MASTER public IP into nginx-ingress-controller via `kubectl edit svc` but it seems not to be a correct solution due to lack of a load balancer itself.

Similar results using helm chart:

```
helm install -n ingress-nginx stable/nginx-ingress --set controller.service.externalIPs[0]="MASTER PUBLIC IP"
```

Comment: Hi, I am facing the same issue as you. Did you manage to make it work with NodePort?

Answer (score 3):

> I was able to make it working forcing LoadBalancer service type and setting externalIP value as a MASTER public IP into nginx-ingress-controller via kubectl edit svc but it seems not to be a correct solution due to lack of a load balancer itself.

Correct, that is not what [LoadBalancer](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#loadbalancer) is intended for. It's intended for provisioning load balancers with cloud providers like AWS, GCP, or Azure, or a load balancer that has some sort of API so that the kube-controller-manager can interface with it. If you look at your kube-controller-manager logs you should see some errors.  The way you made it work it's obviously a hack, but I suppose it works.

The standard way to implement this is just to use a [NodePort](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#nodeport) service and have whatever proxy/load balancer (i.e. nginx, or haproxy) on your master to send traffic to the NodePorts. Note that I don't recommend the master to front your services either since it already handles some of the critical Kubernetes pods like the kube-controller-manager, kube-apiserver, kube-scheduler, etc.

The only exception is [MetalLB](https://metallb.universe.tf) which you can use with a LoadBalancer service type. Keep in mind that as of this writing the project is in its early stages.

Comment: What about MetalLB? I mean MetalLB + nginx-ingress-controller ?

Comment: @YasiuMaster. MetalLB should work with type LoadBalancer. Make sure you follow the docs and keep in mind that the project in its early stages.